# Error: Expected a value of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart, hue

I'm using [hue_dart](https://pub.dev/packages/hue_dart) package and try to show me implemented lights in my hue bridge, but I get this Error:

```
Instance of `_Future<List<Light>>`
Error: Expected a value of type `Map<dynamic, dynamic>', but got one of type 'List<dynamic>'
```

How to convert this list to map, or how to display the list of lights?

This is my code:

```
class HueBridge {
  searchBridge() async {
    final client = Client();
    final discovery = BridgeDiscovery(client);

    List<DiscoveryResult> discoverResults = await discovery.automatic();
    final discoveryResult = discoverResults.first;

    final bridge = Bridge(client, discoveryResult.ipAddress);
    print(discoveryResult.ipAddress);

    final lights = bridge.lights();
    print(lights);
  }
}
```

Comment: In the debug terminal shows the current line where error ocurrs, can you write this line?

Comment: it happens when I add `final lights = bridge.lights();`. That is how the doc to this package tell me to search for lights connected to bridge.

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to use the hue_dart package and encountered the same issue. A pull request have been written to fix this problem, it was accepted and merged but not released on the pub.dev.

Issue : https://github.com/Jairzinno/hue_dart/issues/8
PR : https://github.com/Jairzinno/hue_dart/pull/9

You have to know the hue_dart package is not developed by Philips, and seems to not be maintained. Indeed Philips released a V2 of their API but the package use the deprecated API V1.

To fix your issue you have 2 options :

- Make the same changes as the PR (not recommended because in case of "flutter pub get" you will lose your updates).
- Clone directly the GitHub of the package.

I'm actually using this package, but I'm thinking about creating a new hue_dart package to use the new V2 API.